# Create unique PostgreSQL constraint with static value

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have columns `A`, `B` and `C` as `FK INT, FK INT, BOOL`. Is it possible to do a `unique` constraint like `UNIQUE(A, B, C = true)`, where I can have duplicates of `A`, `B`, `C` so long as `C` is `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a partial unique index:

```
create unique index idx_abc on tablename (a, b, c) where (c);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b6ec41a1747da6cafa309f64cc48187).

Comment: Actually `on tablename (a, b) where (c)` is enough here.